# Binding Parsed conent to a hyperlink button

Tags: xaml, user-interface, windows-phone-8, data-binding

This is relating to Windows Phone 8.0

I have parsed some data relating to a dynamic store logo and a dynamic URL.

The Logo is displayed via :

```
<Image Source="{Binding StoreLink}" />
```

The URL as text is displayed via :

```
<TextBlock Name="DLlink" Text="{Binding DLlink}" />
```

However, as that is a TextBlock it can't be used as a URL.

Ideally, I would like to combine the two somehow. So the user would tap the {Binding StoreLink} image and be directed to the {Binding DLlink} URL.

However, I have tried the following with no success :

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="Download Link" NavigateUri="{Binding Name=DLlink}" />
```

and;

```
<TextBlock>
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding DLlink}" />
</TextBlock>
```

What I am doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try registering `TouchUp` event for your image where you can naviagte to your DLink url from code.

Or you can try this.

```
<HyperlinkButton
    NavigateUri={Binding Name="DLink"}>
    <HyperlinkButton.Content>
       <Image Source={ Binding Name="StoreLink"} />
    </HyperlinkButton.Content>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

Comment: Error : The property 'Name' was not found in type 'Binding'.  I tried ElementName and it ran the code but did not display anything.

Comment: Changed to <HyperlinkButton.Background><ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding StoreLink}" /></HyperlinkButton.Background>

Comment: Can you please edit the answer for what worked for you. And ya. Remove name and keep it just Binding DLink

Answer (score 3):

Modify your Hyperlink Button to this..

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="Download Link"
                 NavigateUri="{Binding DLlink}"
                 TargetName="_blank" />
```

This should work.

Comment: +1 To expand on this, could also throw both his image and his text into the content of the HyperlinkButton so he'd get his combination of the two that he's looking for.

Comment: Error : The member "Name" is not recognized or is not accessible - code would not run. Changed to Elementname and the code ran, showed the button but on click nothing happened.

Comment: remove the name part from the binding. Its my mistake i copied it from your code. You should derectly bind the Property `DLlink` to the `NavigateUri`. It works i have tested it.